# Why produces this code a "assignment from incompatible pointertype" warning?

Tags: c, arrays, shell, pointers, struct

I'm writing a shell at my own and I'm always getting this warning "assignment from incompatible pointertype" for the following code(just the important lines)

```
if (first_struct == NULL)
            {
                first_struct = &parg;
            }
            else
            {

                Pargs** temp = first_struct;
                while ((*temp)->next != NULL)
                    temp = &((*temp)->next);<--incompatible pointer type
                (*temp)->next = parg;<--incompatible pointer type

            }
            parg->next = NULL;
```

For me there are just the same pointer types.

Here is the code for the struct:

```
    typedef struct
{
    struct Pargs* next;
    char* command;
    char* args[11];
} Pargs;
```

The struct was declared a few lines above:

```
Pargs* parg = malloc(sizeof (Pargs));
```

Maybe I do not see my own fails, but I look at this lines since hours and I have no idea why this should be not correct.

PS: If anyone needs more code or information, please do not hesitate to ask, I have many more of them ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 typedef struct
 {
    struct Pargs* next;         
    char* command;
    char* args[11];
} Pargs;
```

You refer to typedef `Pargs` inside struct itself . That won't work as it is a pointer to incomplete type and you can't refer to it , until you give complete definition.

You can do this instead -

```
typedef struct name                // give any desired name to structure
{
     struct name *next;             //use struct's name to declare pointer next
     char* command;
     char* args[11];
} Pargs;
```